# Update Rating total as a % using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok we are making a rating script, in fact it all works.

The code is split across 20 ratings, that we require users to rate. They have each 10 values.

Code like so:

```
<div class="ctrlHolder">
<p class="label">Housing Affordability</p>
<div class="multiField starify" id="question-1">
    <label for="vote-1_1" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_1" data-cost="0" value="Very Poor" /> Very Poor</label>
    <label for="vote-1_2" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_2" data-cost="1.0" value="Poor" /> Poor</label>
    <label for="vote-1_3" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_3" data-cost="1.5" value="Not that Bad" /> Not that Bad</label>
    <label for="vote-1_4" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_4" data-cost="2.0" value="Fair" /> Fair</label>
    <label for="vote-1_5" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_5" data-cost="2.5" value="Average" /> Average</label>
    <label for="vote-1_6" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_6" data-cost="3.0" value="Almost" /> Almost</label>
    <label for="vote-1_7" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_7" data-cost="3.5" value="Good" /> Good</label>
    <label for="vote-1_8" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_8" data-cost="4.0" value="Very Good" /> Very Good</label>
    <label for="vote-1_9" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_9" data-cost="4.5" value="Excellent" /> Excellent</label>
    <label for="vote-1_10" class="blockLabel"><input type="radio" name="poll-1" id="vote-1_10" data-cost="5.0" value="Perfect" /> Perfect</label>
</div>
```

ABove shows 1 question. Or sorry one Rating, which appears like this:

[image]

Now the user selects the amount of stars they think that QUESTION affords, so in this example the user has selected 8 stars , for Housing Affordability.

This is appended a data-cost of 4.0

Because we have 20 questions, the maths is like so:

20 questions = 100% max score rating. ( if users 10 stars everything. )

Thus each question is worth 5% of total score, and because there are 10 stars in each rating, each star has a individual value of .5%

So in this case, above 8 star rating = 4%

What I want to achieve, is...

As the user goes thru the questions we have a FIXED div, which updates the current rating %

Like so:

[image]

What I need is some help doing the jQuery.

I need to echo the current selection from question 1, into the Your Rating: element.

And update it as we go, so if user rates next item 8 stars , the rating shows 8%
and updates on page as they go thru the ratings.

To keep it tidy, I have split the rating page into 4, and we paginate across the rating pages, 1 to 4 using back and next.

Obviously we need to add validation as we go, but wondered if anyone knows method to do what I want to achieve...

I had read about (prop) method, but I am getting confused.

Any help appreciated, please.

To CLARIFY:

data-cost isnt used anywhere else, it is just something I have added to do the math as we go

UPDATE:

DEMO setup. http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/starrating/demo7c.html

Issue seems to be each rating is cloaked into a sibling div.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: now with unique IDs

Try something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmSsu/1/)

For future reference. If the link is broken. Check Gaby's code. It's almost exactly the same.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't really matter for this example.

Comment: It does when it messes up the `<label>`s, and I can't select the radiobuttons properly. It's also a bad example to set to an OP who may not realise that you've deliberately left this error (which causes the HTML to be invalid) in your code.

Comment: just gonna check that out, thankyou. As @Tomalak says, each question has unique ids.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: thought it to be an obvious error, but you're right it might not be to everyone. I updated the link in my answer.

Comment: Please post the code here in addition to the link.  Links to external sites tend to rot, and that will make your answer useless to people who find the answer via search in the future.

Comment: Gaby aka G. Petrioli came up with almost exactly the same code. Seems a bit redundant to also post my code here at this moment. Made a reference to Gaby's code though.

Answer (score 2):

This function will calculate the rating for you on the current page making each star worth 0.5%:

```
function getRating(){
    var rating = 0;
    $('input[id^="vote-"]:checked').each(function(){
        rating += $(this).attr('id').match(/vote-\d+_(\d+)/)[1]/2;
        }
    );
    return rating;
}
```

You can use that on a change event for your inputs like:

```
$('input[id^="vote-"]').change(function(){
    var rating = getRating();
    // Add in value from previous page
    // Somewhere around here
    $('#rating-display').text(rating+'%');
});
```

Comment: Hey Paul, will give that a whirl.

Comment: To clarify, thematch function returns an array of elements which match the regex provided and you're extracting the rating out or the ID? Clever :)

Comment: Have updated question with sample code, seemingly... we have an issue HOUSTON

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `data-cost` attribute you can do this

```
var rating=0;
$('.starify :checked').each(function(){
  rating += +$(this).data('cost');
});
```

and just show this on some element with

```
$('someid').text(rating);
```

Tie all this to the radio-button click event, and you are set..

```
$('.starify :radio').live('click', function(){
    var rating=0;
    $('.starify :checked').each(function(){
      rating += +$(this).data('cost');
    });

    $('someid').text(rating);
});
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9767h/1/

---

**Update**

If you do not use the `data-cost` attribute, as is the case in your live example, then you can use the index of the radio-button (*or its parent label in this case*) in the group of stars.

```
$('.starify :radio').live('click', function(){
    var rating=0;
    $('.starify :checked').each(function(){
      rating += ($(this).parent().index()+1) * 0.5;
    });

    $('#rating').text(rating + ' %');
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7BAuk/

Comment: Haha, great minds think alike. Check the link in my answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks, have updated question. Seemingly, the issue arises from the rating system we are using.

Comment: @Ewout, *chuckle* .. but i put the `%` symbol after the rating (*in the fiddle*) :p

Comment: Could you guys see if you could get it working with this code? http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/starrating/demo7c.html

Comment: @422, your example does not use the `data-cost` attribute. See this for a solution using the index of the stars.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7BAuk/

Comment: @Gaby - its not working due to not having data-cost in the form, its due to the form being converted away from an input (firebug inspect the star ratings).

Comment: Good Onya, just checking if it will work LIVE. Yeah I used data-cost because value already has a value ( echoing the Rating string ) Your sample works, in a fiddle. but if you were to use the code in the URL i posted, you will see it doesnt echo the % value .. we get NaN

Comment: I can add the data-cost vals in if it helps ?

Comment: @422 you get NAN because i use the `data-cost` in my code. I have posted an update that does not use it and calculates the star rating based on the actual star item..

Comment: uPDATED url CODE: TO INCLUDE YOUR CODE: http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/starrating/demo7c.html As you see it isnt appending the values correctly .. for some bloody reason

Comment: @422.. the code in your page is not the code i posted.. You have changed the class names ,and altered the calculation .. My code was meant to work as-is (*i am using the correct classes from your code*).